# Maximum axis x Chart c#

Tags: c#, charts

I'm working on a project where I work with two graphs, and on the lower graph if I see the maximum of the x-axis (24) but on the upper graph no. How can I make it appear up on 24? I am using the chart windows in visual studio, the default chart in windows forms

[Chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoFla.png)

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i,1+i);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some more detail about how your charts are drawn.

Comment: Hi, an [mcve] will help. We need information about the charts lib you are using, and the code showing the configuration of your grid will be usefull. Without it, the best answer could be "configure it to show the maxium". And the exact way of doing it will differt for each chats lib.

Comment: I am using the chart windows in visual studio, the default chart in windows forms

Comment: Try `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to (more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Maximum/Minimum controls the length of the Axis
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 30;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 30;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;

        // Interval controls the interval between values on the chart
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, 1 + i);

        }
    }
}
```

Chart looks like:

[image]